Server Side Tagging for Google Tag Manager Android
I am trying to implement server side tagging for an android app by following the instructions in section 3 of this link: https://developers.google.com/tag-platform/tag-manager/server-side/send-data?option=GTM#mobile_apps
However, I am stuck on step 3, which says:
Set the value of Image URL to a pixel image on the server container at the path in the Measurement Protocol client that you specified earlier. Append any desired Measurement Protocol parameters to the end of your pixel URL:
https://custom.example.com/app?v=1&tid=TAG_ID&cid=555&t=screenview&an=myApp&version=1.6.2&aid=com.foo.myapp&cd=home
Can anyone walk me through how I should set up this pixel image?

please read
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters
https://developers.google.com/tag-platform/tag-manager/server-side
